# How to avoid catch redundancy in express node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have multiple calls in a process inside in a Route, I find myself obliged to duplicate the "catch" process several times :

```
 Marque.one(createOrder.Order_marque).then(function(m){ 
    Forfaits.oneByIdExt(id).then(function(forfait) { 
        createOrder["donneur_ordre_id"] = parseInt(forfait[0].donneur_ordre_id)
        createOrder["structure_juridique_id"] = parseInt(forfait[0].structure_juridique_id)
        OrderEntries.insertOrderEntries(m[0].Marque, idPlan, createUser, createOrder, req.user.id).then(function (data) {
            Order.createOrder(createOrder, createUser, req.body.Cart) 
            .then(function (num_cmd) {
                if(forfait[0].tid != null){
                    OrderTP.insert(createTP).then(function (){
                        res.status(200).json({return: 200, returnLabel: 'OK', data: {num_cmd}});
                    })
                }else {
                    res.status(200).json({return: 200, returnLabel: 'OK', data: {num_cmd}});
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                res.status(500).json({return: 500, returnLabel: 'KO', data:{}});
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            res.status(500).json({return: 500, returnLabel: 'KO', data:{}});
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(500).json({return: 500, returnLabel: 'KO', data:{}});
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    res.status(500).json({return: 500, returnLabel: 'KO', data:{}});
});
```

At the beginning I only put the last one but it does not catch the other errors which follow in the other call, how to avoid such a replication of the same code which is really not beautiful ?

Thank You

Comment: Use async await with one try catch :)

Comment: Or simply put your catch on the most outer call (mind I'm assuming that errors bubble).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use async await and wrap your code in try catch block.
example:

```
async handlePromise(){
  try {
     const fist_prmise = await FistPromise();
     const second_promise = await SecondPromise();
  }catch(e){
     console.log(e)
  }
}
```

second promise waiting until first promise resolve

Comment: Thank for your answer it looks good, i put the final response (res.status) like that i hope is good also ? 

`try {

     const fist_prmise = await FistPromise();

     const second_promise = await SecondPromise();

res.status(200).json({return: 200, returnLabel: 'OK', data: {numCmd}}); `

Comment: Yes you can. If you want to terminate the process and return a response use return  like :    

return res.status(200).json(yourResponseData)